# Y-stepper very hot on 4.2.2 board?

Tags: creality-ender-3, stepper, heat-management

Is there a known issue where the Y-stepper gets extremely hot (like 70-80 °C) on the Creality 4.2.2 board while the Y stepper stays around 40 °C on the 4.2.7 board? (two different printers)

Set both of them to run a custom G-code file where it just moves the bed back and forth from 20 to 200 at F1500 (took that from the printer startup code in Cura).

It's not the motor. I had another Ender to borrow one from.

The strangest thing is it happens even when idle. (I did the aforementioned test with the X stepper, which did not get hot at all, but the Y stepper did while the bed was not moving at all).

Comment: Before you shell out for the expense of a new motor only to discover it's not a motor problem, check your stepper driver current settings. I'm not familiar with the specific driver, but you should be able to find a reference online. Also, it may be less expensive to stick a heat sink to the motor surface. I did that for my printer's extruder stepper motors. Dropped the temperature 20 °C.

Comment: Actually I just swapped it out with a motor from another ender. (Same motor part number. ) And its still doing it. So it is not the motor. Oddly the X/Z steppers do not have the same issue. I'll measure the current. I can build a custom JST extension that I can run through an ammeter.

Answer (score 1):

The Creality 4.2.2 board uses A4988 stepper drivers which set the current through the steppers via a potentiometer on the driver itself. The Creality 4.2.7 board used 2208 (Trinamic) stepper drivers, of which the current through the steppers is defined in the advanced configuration.

If the motor runs hotter on the first (4.2.2 board) you need to adjust the potentiometer to the correct Vref (reference voltage).

From [All3D.com](https://www.all3dp.com/2/vref-calculator-tmc2209-tmc2208-a4988/):

> Vref is calculated with a simple formula:
>
> Vref ​= I​ x 8 x Rsense
>
> Where I is the driver current to the motors and Rsense is the current sense resistor. While I is primarily defined by the motor’s rated current, Rsense is a fixed value that can be verified by checking the stepstick board.
>
> Sense resistors vary from vendor to vendor, ranging from 0.05 up to 0.2 Ω. Look for two equal resistors in the A4988, as shown in the image above. In this example, R100 is 100 mΩ, or 0.1 Ω.
>
> Although the stepper motor we’ll use here is rated for 0.9 A, we should never set it to its maximum current capacity. It’s strongly recommended to reduce the amount of current to the motor by at least 10%, which in our case would translate to approximately 0.8 A.

If you want the second to use more current, and thus run hotter, the current specification needs to be increased. You can alter this in the configuration or use `M906` G-code.